# Trying to display different scores on the multiple bar graphs plotted in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

Still a beginner in coding.
I have created a  multiple bar graphs  on a single plot and now wanted scores to print on the two different bargraphs.
Since both the bar graphs are taken from different dataframes i am able to print only one bar  graph i.e. scores considered from data (mentioned in the code). However printing is happening because of the for loop, plt.text but not on the correct bar graph as in the position of printing is incorrect.

And please suggest how to print on the first/second bar graph  for which i need to select the scores from data and Data1

```
X = ['A','B','C']
data = customer_survey_TSS['Advocacy4']/4
Data1 = Emp_Survey_TSS['Advocacy']

  
X_axis = np.arange(len(X))

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10, 5)

  
plt.bar(X_axis - 0.2, data, 0.4, label = 'Customer scores')
plt.bar(X_axis + 0.2, Data1, 0.4, label = 'Employee scores')
  

plt.xticks(X_axis, X)
plt.xlabel("Quarters-FY21")
plt.ylabel("Aggregate score of customer & Employee")
plt.title("Customer-Employee")
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1.0), loc='upper left')

    for index,data in enumerate(VOC):
        plt.text(x=index , y =data+0.0065 , s=f"{data}" , fontdict=dict(fontsize=13))
        

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: See this: [https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html)

Comment: And since you're working with dataframes, consider combining the relevant columns in 1 dataframe and using [`df.plot.bar()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html).